# Xcode 7 UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete Crash

Tags: ios, uitableview

I created a table with custom cells. I have a problem when I run the deletion of a line. The app crashes.

Here follows the code why?

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Location.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    HomeModel *_homeModel;
    NSArray *_feedItems;
    Location *_selectedLocation;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController
```

The table is loaded with some elements taken from a remote MySQL DB and imported in each row.

```
-(void)itemsDownloaded:(NSArray *)items
{
    _feedItems = items;
    [self.listTableView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark Table View Delegate Methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _feedItems.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"BasicCell"; 
    CustomCell *myCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}
return myCell;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.listTableView.delegate = self;
    self.listTableView.dataSource = self;

    _feedItems = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    _homeModel = [[HomeModel alloc] init];
    _homeModel.delegate = self;
    [_homeModel downloadItems];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    _selectedLocation = _feedItems[indexPath.row];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailSegue" sender:self];
}
```

I modified the code this way

```
#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
     [self.listTableView beginUpdates];
     [self.listTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
     [self.listTableView endUpdates];
    }
}
```

The error received is now:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (5) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (5), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: What is the crash message?

Comment: No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'removeObjectAtIndex:'

Comment: feedItems is an NSArray, not an NSMutableArray. You should declare it as NSMutableArray and say `_feedItems= [items mutableCopy];` in `itemsDownloaded`

Comment: Property 'feedItems' not found on object of type 'ViewController *'

Comment: Sorry, yes I updated my comment. I assumed your were using s property but it is just an ivar

Comment: Does not change, the type of error is the same ... :-(

Comment: Did you change the declaration for the variable?  What about the initialisation in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: Check everything again. Are you getting a runtime error or a compiler warning. What you listed above is a compiler message. If you get a runtime crash, update your question with the exception message and check which line it crashes on

Answer (score 0):

Take the item that you're deleting out of your `_feedItems` array before you begin updates for the table.